# JSON for JQueryUI autocomplete - Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working on an autocomplete form field and am having a little trouble formatting the JSON I want to pass into this. I'm using an ID field for the autocomplete, though the JSON is returning as follows:

```
{"users":["12345","23456","34567", ... ]}
```

As I understand it, I need an array of data for JQuery's autocomplete - which I'm using - though I can't seem to lose the hash surrounding this. Any advice? Or if I'm going wrong elsewhere, guidance would be great!

Here's the other relevant code to this:

JS

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
    $( "#user_****Id" ).autocomplete({
      source: $('#user_****Id').data('autocomplete-source')
    })
})
```

Form (haml)

```
= simple_form_for [:admins, @user] do |f|
  ...
  = f.input :****Id, input_html: { data: { autocomplete_source: new_admins_user_path } }
  ...
```

Controller

```
def new
    @hospitals = Hospital.all
    @hospitals_autocomplete = @hospitals.map(&:id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @hospitals_autocomplete}
    end
  end
```

Thanks everyone - Steve.

Comment: I'm not aware of haml plugging into jquery in any way. What's in `data-autocomplete-source`? Looks like it should be a string, not an array

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for autocomplete,I would recommend [Jquery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), I have used it myself and its easy to setup.let me show you an example:-

**in your form fields**

```
<% form_for(@user,:url=>new_user_path) do |f|%>

//other input text and text area fields
//autocomplete field to add tag to user and also show existing tags
//suppose this field is user_tag_list
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, "data-pre" => @user.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json  %>
<%end%>
```

**in js code:-**

```
//activate the autocomplete text field(user_tag_list) and call ajax to return json from the controller
   $("#user_tag_list").tokenInput("/users/show_user_tags.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    placeholder: "Add your Favorite user tags",
    prePopulate: $("#user_tag_list").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook",
    hintText: "Tag this user with your fav tags",
    noResultsText: "Well,search for you fav tags",
    searchingText: "here it comes <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg'></i>",
    tokenLimit:3,
    //add title to search on basis of title on form submit
    tokenValue: 'name',
    resultsLimit:10,
    resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li><p><span style='font-size:1em !important;'><b>" + item.name + "</b></span></p></li>" },
    tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.name + "</p></li>" },
    preventDuplicates: true
  });
```

**controller code ...that calls show_user_tags in users controller**

```
def show_user_tags
  @tags = UserTag.where("title like ?", "#{params[:q].capitalize}%")
  @tags = @tags.map do |c|
      { :id => c.id,:name => c.title}
    end   
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @tags }
    end
 end
```